# Drop in replacement for django.utils.simplejson that handles Decimal encoding?

Tags: python, django, simplejson

With the deprecation and removal of `django.utils.simplejson` in 1.7, the suggested drop in replacement is the builtin `json` module. However the builtin doesn't handle encoding of `Decimal` fields when using `dumps()` like `simplejson` does. Using `django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder` i.e.

```
>>> string = json.dumps({"x", Decimal("100.000000")}, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
>>> '{"x": "100.000000"}'
```

seems to convert the decimal to a string before encoding, whereas

```
>>> string = simplejson.dumps({"x", Decimal("100.000000")})
>>> '{"x": 100.000000}'
```

Is there an exact replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best match for this that I've found appears to be [ujson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson), it handles decimals just fine.